# Get Childs of Child Firebase Database to Listview

Tags: android, firebase, listview, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to get the childs of a child from a database on firebase on a listview. The firebase structure is this one: [Firebase database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DXiYb.png).
When i run the following code my App crashes when starting that activity. 
My code is the following:

```
    String TripIDD = intent.getStringExtra(AvailableRides.EXTRA_MESSAGE9);

    final DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    final DatabaseReference tripsRef = rootRef.child("Trips").child(TripIDD);
    ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            List<String> passengers = new ArrayList<String>();
            ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, passengers);
            ListView Passengers = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.passengerslist);
            for (final DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                String user = ds.child("Passengers on the ride").getValue(String.class);
                passengers.add(user);
                Passengers.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this, you need to query your database, twice:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference tripsRef = rootRef.child("Trips");
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String key = ds.getKey();

            DatabaseReference keyRef = tripsRef.child(key).child("Passengers on the ride");
            ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    for(DataSnapshot dSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        String passenger = dSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                        Log.d("TAG", passenger);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
            };
            keyRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
tripsRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

The output will be all the passengers within the `Passengers on the ride` node from all trips.

If you want to get the passengers of only one trip, please use the following code:

```
String TripIDD = intent.getStringExtra(AvailableRides.EXTRA_MESSAGE9);
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference ref = rootRef.child("Trips").child(TripIDD).child("Passengers on the ride");
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String passenger = ds.getValue(String.class);
            Log.d("TAG", passenger);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

In which `TripIDD` is the id of that particular trip that you want to get (e.g. `-L8wwgt3FeQjzAUeTJon`).

Comment: Hi Alex, you are my saver ;) i have a small question, what if I want to get the passengers of only one trip, which is the Trip in the string TripIDD?

Answer (score 1):

For basic write operations, you can use setValue() to save data to a specified reference, replacing any existing data at that path. You can use this method to:
Pass types that correspond to the available JSON types as follows:
String
Long
Double
Boolean
Map
List
Pass a custom Java object, if the class that defines it has a default constructor that takes no arguments and has public getters for the properties to be assigned.
For example, if you have an app with a basic user profile, your User object might look as follows:

```
public class User {
    public String username;
    public String email;
    public User() {
        // Default constructor required for calls to DataSnapshot.getValue(User.class)
    }
    public User(String username, String email) {
        this.username = username;
        this.email = email;
    }
}
```

You can add a user with setValue() as follows:

```
private void writeNewUser(String userId, String name, String email) {
    User user = new User(name, email);
    mDatabase.child("users").child(userId).setValue(user);
}
```

And read it like below

```
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private DatabaseReference mUsersDBRef;
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
    private UsersAdapter adapter;
    private List<User> mUsersList = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_chat_users);

        //assign firebase auth
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        mUsersDBRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
        //initialize the recyclerview variables
        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.usersRecyclerView);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        // use a linear layout manager
        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    }
    private void queryUsersAndAddthemToList(){
            mUsersDBRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    if(dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount() > 0){
                        for(DataSnapshot snap: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                            User user = snap.getValue(User.class);
                            //if not current user, as we do not want to show ourselves then chat with ourselves lol
                            try {
                                if(!user.getUserId().equals(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid())){
                                    mUsersList.add(user);
                                }
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    /**populate listview**/
                    adapter = new UsersAdapter(mUsersList, ChatUsersActivity.this);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
        }
```